# Where can I find the deprecated item's replacement in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated

I need to find the replacement for the deprecated items in java. I found some description in javadoc about each and every deprecated items. But it's not sufficient.

To be more specific => I need to do a java program, which can read a java file and should replace the deprecated items used(if any) in that given java file with the appropriate replacement.

1. Is there any other source to find it?

   OR
2. Is there any third party API's available to give the replacement for the deprecated itms?

   OR
3. Is there any options available in eclipse to do this? -> I mean for example in the problems console of eclipse, we can able to find the warnings for the deprecated items used. Likewise, is there anything in eclipse which can show the replacement of the deprecated items in the project,

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance,

Easwar

Comment: Please be more specific.  Which method/field/class are you referring to?  Usually the suggested replacement is in the javadoc.  When it's not, it can indeed be extremely frustrating.

Comment: What does this have to do with Eclipse?

Comment: HI Kirk Woll, I need generic thing. Could you please give me some suggestion regarding this.

Comment: Hi The Elite Gentlemen, I mean is there any plugin or utilities in eclipse which can show the replacement for the deprecated items.

Comment: @Easwaramoorthy Kanaga, I suggest you make your post clear since it doesn't seem like you're requesting an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman, I have edited my question. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A @Deprecated API (method, class, whatever) is deprecated to notify you that a newer API exists that should be used instead of it. Exactly what the newer API is is not deterministic (i.e. is not something that can be inferred by eclipse or by analyzing the code). The only way to know what should be used instead of it is to read the documentation. If there is no documentation, there is no way of knowing apart from contacting someone who does know.

Comment: Agreed. Would be cool if it was a compiler error if we use `@Deprecation` without documenting the recommended alternative ;-)

Comment: @Gary:  What is the 'newer API' that should be used in replacement of `Thread.stop()`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's all in the first paragraph of the javadoc for [Thread.stop()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()). I recommend reading the [Java tutorial on Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), especially the [section about interrupts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: @Andreas_D You might be able to use [Check Style](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to get a warning...

Comment: @Gary:  "It's all in the first paragraph of the javadoc for Thread.stop()."  Yes.  But what it says suggests a *different approach,* not a new API.

Comment: @AndrewThompson New APIs and new approaches often come hand in hand. The reason for a new API is usually a new approach. The javadoc explains why `stop()` is a bad idea and the new approach of using interrupts is better. You should never purposely kill a thread in mid-execution. You should request that it stops so that it can handle it gracefully.